# How to use function pg_get_pid when pgsql connected by PDO?

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine

I can use `pg_get_pid` when pgsql connected by `pg_connect`:

```
$conn = pg_pconnect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test");
$pid = pg_get_pid($conn);
```

But I need use `pg_get_pid` when pgsql connected by PDO (Doctrine use it):

```
$dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$pid = pg_get_pid(?);
```

How to get `$conn` value for `pg_get_pid($conn)` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sql query:

```
select pg_backend_pid()
```